# Appending an array at the end of a line in perl

Tags: perl

I have more code before this which populates the array @a_nam. Now I want to append the elements in the array @a_nam at the end of the line shown below in abc.txt. I tried something but its not working. please give your inputs.
edited: i tried "+>>" which didnt work.

```
## NAME_id , course, Fall 10 ,spring 11, ........

open my $file, '+>>', 'abc.txt' or die "failed : $!";
while (<$file>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^## NAME(.*)/) {
       print  $file join ",", @a_nam;
    }   
}
close($file);
```

Comment: Please describe how it's not working.  What was the output or error message?

Comment: there was no error. I just dont see it appending in the file. I should have mentioned it. Sorry.

Comment: You're trying to read from a file you opened for appending?

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to append to specific line in file with out creating a backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example using [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html)

I'm not going to repeat @choroba, as he's already explained why your example doesn't work.

**UPDATED**. It will now append the `array` to the end of the line, instead of removing it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::File;
my @a_nam = qw(append some stuff);
my $match = "## NAME";

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', "abc.txt" or die "failed: $!";

for my $line (@lines){
    if( $line =~ /^($match.*)/ ) {
        $line = $1 . ", " . join ', ', @a_nam;
    }
}
untie @lines;
```

File before:

```
1 blah blah
2 ## NAME, foo, bar, baz
3 whatever lines here
```

File after:

```
1 blah blah
2 ## NAME, foo, bar, baz, append, some, stuff
3 whatever lines here
```

Answer (score 4):

You open the file for appending

```
open my $file, '>>'
```

but then you try to read from the file

```
while (<$file>)
```

This is not possible. Open the file for reading and write to another file. At the end, rename the old file to a backup and the new file to the original.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to append to specific line in file with out creating a backup?

Comment: Not without overwriting the beginning of the next line. You can't "grow" a file in the middle. You have to copy everything that comes after the point youre appending at.